# How do I share my Internet connection with another MacBook via WLAN?

Tags: network, sharing

My MacBook is connected to Internet.

I want to share this connection with another MacBook via WLAN.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is your MacBook connected with WiFi or Ethernet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using your WiFi to connect to the internet, you cannot use it to also create a local network for other computers. If you are networked via something not-Wifi (Ethernet, FireWire, USB, etc.) then you can share your connection via WiFi.

[image]

1. Go to System Prefs > Sharing.
2. Select your existing connection under `Share your connection from:`
3. Select `Airport` under `To computers using:`
4. Turn on Internet Sharing with the checkbox on the left.
5. The network name will be the name of your computer.

Comment: Isn't this kind of dangerous, this way you set up an totally unsecured acesspoint. Can it be secured?

Comment: When you turn this on you are prompted to enter a password.

Comment: @richarddas the password doesn't secure the network, it just makes sure you are an admin when you turn it on.